# Multivariate Chain Rule

Tags: calculus

Given:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
R & = & \ln(u^2 + v^2 + w^2)\\
u & = & x + 6y\\
v & = & 2x - y\\
w & = & 4xy
\end{eqnarray}
$$

I am trying to determine $$\frac{\partial R}{\partial x}$$ when $x = y = 2$.

Apparently I am incorrect: (Sorry for the lack of appropriate formatting)

$$\frac{\partial R}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial R}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u} {\partial x}+ \frac{\partial R}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial R}{\partial w}\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$$

$$= (1 / (u^2 + v^2 + w^2)) ((2u) (1) + (2v) (2) + (2w) (4y))$$

$$= (1 / (196 + 4 + 256)) (28 + 8 + 256)$$

$$= 73/114$$

Comment: If $R=4xy$, then $\partial R/\partial x=4y$

Comment: @Américo: That was a problem in the formatting -- should be clearer now.

Comment: @joriki: Thanks! So my comment is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{\partial R}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial R}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial R}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial R}{\partial w}\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}
$$
so
$$
\frac{\partial R}{\partial x}=\frac{2u}{u^2 + v^2 + w^2}1+\frac{2v}{u^2 + v^2 + w^2}2+\frac{2w}{u^2 + v^2 + w^2}4y
$$
at $(x,y)=(2,2)$ we get $u=14, v=2, w=16$ so that
$$
\frac{\partial R}{\partial x}=\frac{28+8+256}{196+4+256}=\frac{292}{456}=\frac{73}{114}
$$

so your answer seems correct to me...

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is correct, [WolframAlpha gets the same result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d/dx%20%28ln%20%28%28x%2b6y%29%5E2%2b%282x-y%29%5E2%2b%284xy%29%5E2%29%29%20where%20x=2,%20y=2).